# Mean and Variance (Without calculator)

Tags: statistics

A machine packs flour into bags.  A random sample of 11 filled bags was taken from the output of the machine and the masses of the bags (measured to the nearest 0.1g) were found to be

$1506.8, 1506.6, 1506.7, 1506.9, 1507.2, 1506.6, 1507.0, 1507.5, 1506.3, 1506.4, 1506.8$

Without using an electronic calculator, obtain the mean and variance of this sample.

Can someone give me some hints for solving this question?

Comment: Hint. Start (with pencil and paper or mentally) by subtracting 1506.3 from all the numbers. You may discover that there's even a better 1506.x to subtract. In either case you'll have much smaller numbers to deal with. Multiply them by 10 if you'd rather play with integers than tenths.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it. I found that using $y=x-1506.8$ is better.

Comment: You can answer your own question here now.

Comment: I've answered. Can you help me check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$\bar{y}=\frac{\sum y}{n}=\frac{0}{11}=0$

$\sigma y=\sqrt{\frac{1.2}{11}-0^2}$

$y=x-1506.8$

So, $\bar{y}=\bar{x}-1506.8$

$0=\bar{x}-1506.8$

$\bar{x}=1506.8$

$\sigma y=\sigma x$

$\sigma x=\sqrt{\frac{1.2}{11}}$

$\sigma x^2=0.109$

Comment: These look OK to me. I don't know how much precision you should be reporting for the variance given the 0.1g precision of the data.